# Differences between these two property implementations?

Tags: c#, static

I'm trying to call the getter of a static variable in another class. Can someone tell me why this works:

```
protected static SymTab _symTab;

public SymTab symTab
{
    get{return _symTab;}
    set{_symTab = value;}
}
```

and this does not:

```
public static SymTab symTab {get; protected set;}
```

Comment: What does not work? Are you trying to call it as an instance method?

Comment: Yeah, that ended up being the problem. Bad Java habits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version has an *instance* property which gets/sets a *static* variable.

The second version has a *static* property which gets/sets a *static* variable. (The setter is protected, too, but that doesn't seem to be your immediate problem.)

I would strongly discourage the first form - instance properties should reflect something about that instance; you wouldn't expect setting a property on one instance to change the property value for a different instance.

With the second form, you can just use:

```
SymTab currentTab = TypeName.symTab;
```

instead of:

```
SymTab currentTab = someVariable.symTab;
```

Additionally, I would note:

- The property name `symTab` violates .NET naming conventions
- The type name `SymTab` isn't as clear as `SymbolTable` or whatever that abbreviation is short for
- Mutable static variables are almost *always* a bad idea.

EDIT: Note that now we know it's coming from Java, that explains the problem you're seeing. In Java, it's legal (but a bad idea) to refer to a static member "via" a variable or other expression. It makes for very confusing code though. For example:

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(someRunnable);
backgroundThread.start();
backgroundThread.sleep(1000);
```

That makes it *look* like you're telling the new thread to sleep, but *actually* it's a call to the static `Thread.sleep` method which causes the *current* thread to sleep. Some Java IDEs will optionally flag this up as a warning or error.

Fortunately, C# doesn't allow this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And I get what you're saying about the naming conventions. This code actually comes from a book on interpreters and compilers. It's all in Java but I'm trying to convert it to C# for the extra challenge and to learn C# in the process.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but since the getter in the second version is still public, why wouldn't `myInstance.symTab` work?

Comment: @deuteros: Because you can't access a *static* member as if it were an instance member (e.g. via a variable) in C#. You can in Java, but that's a deficiency in Java which can lead to unclear code. (I've edited my post to give a bit more detail.)

Comment: Ah, okay. Now it makes sense as to why it can't be done that way in C#, and I see now how the Java code is confusing. Thanks for the explanation and your patience.

Answer (score 1):

There are two differences:

- in the first case, the `symTab` property (consider naming it SymTab instead, to follow conventions) is as instance property. In the second, it's static. So `MyClass.symTab` will work in the second case and not in the first whereas `myInstance.symTab` will work the otherway around.
- in the first case both the getter and the setter of the property are public, whereas in the second, only the getter is, and the setter is protected.

Answer (score 0):

with the first solution you have a public setting with a protected static variable in the back, where with the second solution you get a protected setter already.